# how to logout from a php session - session_destroy doesn't seem to be enough

Tags: session, cookies, php

I'm trying to learn PHP and using sessions. I seen examples about using session_destroy on logout, but I see this in the php documentation:

> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

so what does one need to do upon logout ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's, like, an example answering your question just below the paragraph you just quoted:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

> #### Example #1 Destroying a session with $_SESSION
>
> ```
> <?php
> // Initialize the session.
> // If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
> session_start();
>
> // Unset all of the session variables.
> $_SESSION = array();
>
> // If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
> // Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
> if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
>     $params = session_get_cookie_params();
>     setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
>         $params["path"], $params["domain"],
>         $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
>     );
> }
>
> // Finally, destroy the session.
> session_destroy();
> ?>
> ```

Comment: gah. there is, I've just looked at so many things today, I just didn't see that. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion only this is nesessary

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION["nome"]);  // where $_SESSION["nome"] is your own variable. if you do not have one use only this as follow **session_unset();**
```

Comment: I've seen that nome somewhere else today. what is it suppose to be ?

Comment: You just have to replace nome with the session variable you set.

Answer (score 0):

I've never actually deleted the session ID from the session.  I usually just unset the necessary variables from the session (so if, for instance, you set a logged in user as `$_SESSION['user'] = $userModel;` then I just `unset($_SESSION['user']);`).  To remove the cookie from the user's browser (like the documentation says) do this:

```
setcookie(session_id(), "", time() - 3600);
```

Read `Example #1` from the [`session_destroy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) documentation for more info.

Answer (score 0):

At the first: use the unset() function. So if you have a $_SESSION['user_id'], and you wanne destroy it: unset($_SESSION['user_id'])

You can also use the unset() for cookies or other vars

Second: can we have some code?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using session id. then you can do this

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['id']);
session_destroy();
```

for cookies you can set the cookie time to some past date.

Answer (score 0):

> Only use session_unset() for older deprecated code that does not use
>   $_SESSION.

session_start();

session_unset($_SESSION['email-user']);
session_destroy();`