# session_destroy() not working

Tags: php, session, logout

My session_destroy () does not work. When I logout as a user, and I go back on my browser, show user online. Where I have the error? Thanks. :-)

file login.php

```
<?php
require_once('functions.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if((isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] != '') && (isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password'] != '')){
        $connection = conectDatabase();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" . $_POST['username'] . "' AND password='" . $_POST['password'] . "';";
        $result = $connection->query($query);
        if ($result->num_rows >0){
             session_start(); 
             $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
             header('LOCATION: users.php');  
        } else {
             echo '<p class="formMessage">Username/password do not match !</p>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<p class="formMessage">Username/Password field is empty</p>';
    }
}                        
?>
```

file functions.php

```
<?php
function conectDatabase() {
    $connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'DB');     

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("error DB: " . mysqli_error() . "(" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ").");
    }
    return $connection;
}
?>
```

file logout.php

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header('LOCATION: login.php');
?>
```

Comment: It's 2014, and you still think it's acceptable to store users' passwords in **plaintext** in the database?  Also, what does `"show user online"` mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20939936/653513

Comment: Please use prepared statements as well, using `$_POST` elements directly in SQL is dangerous.

Comment: SQL inject everything !

Answer (score 14):

Modify file logout.php as below:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION);
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    header('LOCATION: login.php');
?>
```

Comment: Also check session_start should be in login.php file as mentioned by Shiv.

Comment: hello. I changed the file but still the same problem. Thnaks :-(

Comment: Add $_SESSION = array(); before header('LOCATION: login.php');

Comment: My info.php  PHP Version 5.3.10-1 ubuntu3.11

Comment: HAve you try $_SESSION = array(); before header('LOCATION: login.php'); and just refresh page some times it is occurring due to browser cache.

Comment: I thought in php 5.3 it works- add before destroy session. session_unregister('username');

Comment: No change, same problem !

Comment: Most probably error in your queries now. Session is destroy but your queries allow to create session again. Do one thing instead of  header('LOCATION: login.php'); use  header('LOCATION: confirm.php'); and write following code on confirm.php file: session_start(); print_r($_SESSION) and check is it print something or not.

Comment: You can also use session erite function to false;

Answer (score 0):

I think your login is also not working because there is no session_start on your login.php file. Start session on your login.php file may it help.

Comment: Hi. I have session_start() on my login.php but not working. Thnaks

Comment: Ok, then follow Dinesh as he mentioned update your file.