# Proper way to handle Ajax response in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using Ajax to logout from page.

**index.php**

```
<a href="" class="logout-button">Logout</a>
```

**custom.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.logout-button').click(function () {
        dataUrl = "mode=logout";
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: dataUrl,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "OK") {
                    location.href = 'login.php';
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**ajax.php**

```
session_start();
$mode = $_POST['mode'];
if ($mode == 'logout'){
  session_unset();
  session_destroy();
  $_SESSION = array();
  echo "OK";
}
```

Sometimes it works as it should. But sometimes it just reload to same page, even if session is already deleted.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can check if OK is passed in response tab of your browser in such failure situation. In addition you can check session destroy as `if(session_destroy())` send OK otherwise the failure message

Comment: I'd advise not to use ajax for a simple logout. This is like killing rad roaches with a fat man. Just link the user to logout page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939877/how-to-logout-from-a-php-session-session-destroy-doesnt-seem-to-be-enough